# Общая схема обработки событий в паттерне MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Хочу выяснить схему обработки событий при использовании паттерна MVVM.

1. Как я понимаю, ни одного обработчика события в коде быть не должно, так как они возможны только в code behind, а его использовать плохо, так?
2. Вся обработка событий происходит через команды. Для этого надо писать простенький класс вроде этого, в который вставлять свои делегаты, создавать свойства-команды и привязывать их к элементам?

   ```
   class RelayCommand : ICommand
   {
       private Action<object> _executeDelegate;
       public RelayCommand(Action<object> executeDelegate)
       {
           _executeDelegate = executeDelegate;
       }
       public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
       {
           return true;
       }

       public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

       public void Execute(object parameter)
       {
           _executeDelegate(parameter);
       }
   }
   ```
3. А как обрабатывать разные события от одного и того же элемента? Как я понял, команда выполняется для какого-то одного "основного" события?
4. Можно ли получить аргументы события (те же аргументы, что и у обычного обработчика)?
5. Есть ли какие-то более красиве методы? Например, через привязку команд? Только как эти привязки добвлять в окно, если ViewModel не имеет ссылки на него?

Answer (score 6):

1, 2. На мой вкус, не совсем так.

Правильное место для обработчиков событий — UI-специфические задания. Например, вы хотите измерить какой-нибудь контрол, и если его ширина менее 10% контейнера, то скрыть его полностью. Для этого вы подписываетесь на событие изменения размера. Это специфическая задача уровня презентации, которая к VM не имеет никакого отношения. Использовать для неё команду — неправильно, вам не нужна тут слабая связанность.

3. Обычно элемент не должен иметь в своём интерфейсе две команды. Например, для кнопки единственное событие, которое может быть интересно VM-уровню — это нажатие самой кнопки. Изменение размера кнопки для VM интереса не представляет. Соответственно, кнопка (`Button`) имеет лишь одну команду.

Если вы пишете кастомный контрол, который реально может произвести несколько различных интересным для VM-уровня событий, определите в нём несколько команд.

4. Не могу ничего прибавить к точке зрения @ixSci: для этого есть `CommandParameter`.

5. Есть возможность *ещё* уменьшить связность, воспользовавшись предопределёнными командами. Пример: пункт меню может объявить своей командой предопределённую команду `ApplicationCommands.Save` (`<MenuItem Header="Сохранить" Command="Save" ... />`), и привязать имплементацию команды `Save` где-то в другом месте кода (см. `CommandBinding`).

Comment: Да вот, например, подписываться на событие `CommandBinding.Executed` нужно из code behind? VM которая не является code behind ссылки на View не имеет по идее, да?

Comment: @RussCoder: Я делал по-другому: VM создавала `CommandBinding`'и, передавала их в `MainVM`, а приложение при инициализации выполняло `foreach (var binding in mainVM.GlobalBindings) CommandManager.RegisterClassCommandBinding(typeof(Window), binding);`. Подписываться в code-behind получилось не нужно.

Comment: @RussCoder: Но самый простой сценарий, конечно, выставлять команду как свойство VM.

Answer (score 3):

1. Это так, но любая максима есть глупость. Поэтому надо смотреть по обстоятельствам. В любом случае это то, к чему нужно стремиться.
2. Да, либо же использовать готовые MVVM библиотеки, типа MVVM Light.
3. В уже упомянутой мною MVVM Light есть такая штука как `EventToCommand`, пример можно посмотреть [тут](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn237302.aspx)
4. У команды есть `CommandParameter`, туда Вы можете передавать всё, что угодно: `<Button Command="{Binding SomeCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>`