# Как отследить событие контента в SplitView?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp

У меня есть некий SpilitView на панели которого есть некий TextBox. И мне хотелось бы чтобы тыкая различные кнопки на SpilitView content содержание текстбокса менялось в соответствии моей фантазии.  (вот xaml если я не смог объяснить о чем речь)

```
<SplitView.Pane>
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBox Text="Измени меня если сможешь" />     
    </StackPanel>
</SplitView.Pane>
<SplitView.Content>
    <Frame x:Name="MyFrame"/> <!-- Здеся некий фрейм с 3 кнопками: желтая синяя и красная -->
</SplitView.Content>
```

Comment: Ну, а почему бы не привязать текст на текстбоксе к свойству VM, и меняйте его как вздумается. Например, по нажатию на кнопку можно отправить в VM команду.

Comment: А что такое свойство VM? @VladD

Comment: Ну, я думал, что вы пользуетесь паттерном MVVM. Ну если просто, то это объект, который присваивается вашему `DataContext`'у, и можно привязывать свойства UI-элементов к свойствам этого объекта или его подобъектов. Раз вы не пользуетесь MVVM, обязательно прочитайте, как будет время, это основной паттерн в WPF/UWP.

Comment: Если я правильно понял, то я частично этим пользовался... Просто не знал, что это так именуется...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну например как-то так. Для начала определим `VM`:

```
class VM : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public VM()
    {
        ChangeGreetingCommand = new RelayCommand(_ => Greeting = "Ну ты монстр!");
    }

    string greeting = "Измени меня если сможешь";
    public string Greeting
    {
        get { return greeting; }
        set { if (greeting != value) { greeting = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); } }
    }

    public ICommand ChangeGreetingCommand { get; }

    void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

Класс `RelayCommand` можно спереть, например, [отсюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/463209/10105).

Дальше всё просто. Устанавливаете любым образом `VM` в качестве `DataContext`'а вашему корневому элементу (окну или что там в UWP). Текстбокс определяете как

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Greeting}" />
```

Кнопку определяете как

```
<Button Text="Нажми меня, если не боишься" Command="{Binding ChangeGreetingCommand}"/>
```

Вот вроде бы и всё.