# Доступ к TextBlock элементам в ListBox.ItemTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Есть вот такой XAML (читайте комментарии в коде):

```
<ListBox Grid.Row="0" x:Name="lbListOps">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Border Margin="5" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="SteelBlue" CornerRadius="4" Width="370">
                    <Grid Margin="3">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding NameOps}"/>
                        <ListView Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding OpsWindows}">
                            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Grid>
                                        <Grid.ContextMenu>
                                            <ContextMenu>
                                                <MenuItem Header="Copy Window Name" Click="WindowName_MenuItem_Click"></MenuItem> 
/* вот в обработчике событий этого контекстного меню */
                                                <MenuItem Header="Copy ID"></MenuItem>
                                            </ContextMenu>
                                        </Grid.ContextMenu>
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
/* нужно обратиться к этим TextBlock'ам */
                                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Path=Name}" FontWeight="Bold"></TextBlock>
                                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Padding="3 0 0 0" Text="{Binding Path=TeamViewerId}">

                                        </TextBlock>
                                    </Grid>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        </ListView>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>

    </ListBox>
```

Я знаю что есть Sender в обработчиках и нужно как-то его использовать, но имени TextBlock я не знаю.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы подходите неправильно. Вы *можете* пробить результат силой на вашем пути, но лучше идти по-другому.

Правильный путь такой: вы не пытаетесь пролезть через контролы и найти то, что вам нужно, а отправляете команду в VM, и там уж есть доступ ко всему, что надо.

Пример.

```
class OpsWindow : ViewModelBase
{
    public OpsWindow()
    {
        WindowNameCopyCommand = new RelayCommand(o => OnWindowNameCopy(); });
    }

    public string Name { get; set; } // тут реализация INotifyPropertyChanged
    public int TeamViewerId { get; set; } // и тут
    public ICommand WindowNameCopyCommand { get; }

    void OnWindowNameCopy()
    {
        // тут у вас есть доступ к чему угодно
        MessageBox.Show(Name);
    }
}
```

Соответственно ваш XAML исправляется на такой:

```
<MenuItem Header="Copy Window Name" Command="{Binding WindowNameCopyCommand}"/>
```

Реализацию `RelayCommand` можно найти где угодно, например в вашем MVVM-фреймворке. На крайний случай, публиковалось несколько раз на сайте (например, [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/463209/10105)).

---

Для сравнения, то же самое, реализованное при помощи подхода «пробраться через UI»:

```
void WindowName_MenuItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // жёстко прописываем тип элемента MenuItem
    var item = (MenuItem)sender;
    // жёстко прописываем тип элемента ContextMenu
    var menu = (ContextMenu)item.Parent;
    // жёстко кодируем, что мы в верхней части контекстного меню, и что
    // родительский элемент - Grid
    var grid = (Grid)menu.PlacementTarget;
    // жёстко прописываем индексы дочерних элементов
    var textblock1 = (TextBlock)grid.Children[0];
    var textblock2 = (TextBlock)grid.Children[1];
    // можно пользоваться
}
```

Comment: Т.е. я могу наплодить подобные команды и "забиндить" в любом элементе для доступа к нужному элементу?

Comment: @cyberdream: Конечно!